# How to make a section of code callable later

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just for refrence this is a shop that works. I was just wondering if its possible to make it callable at another time. For example

```
    x = input("If you want to go to shop type 'Yes'")
    if x == "Yes":
```

I don't know it its possible but I think it would need a function and it would call that big block of code. Any help is appreciated.

```
    shopitemsF = ["Ghostblade: 150 Damage, Cost: 700", "Thunderblade: 120 Damage, Cost: 300", "Bloodcursed Sword: 160 Damage, Cost 800"]
    shopitemsM = ["Fire Throw: 150 Damage, Cost: 700", "Ice Wind: 120 Damage, Cost: 300", "Electric shock: 160 Damage, Cost 800"]


    print("Welcome to the shop.")
    print('')
    if character == "Fighter":
        g = ', '
        print(g.join(shopitemsF))
        time.sleep(1)
    elif character == "Mage":
        g = ', '
        print(g.join(shopitemsM))
        time.sleep(1)

    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
    print('')

    found = False
    while found != True:
        for text2 in shopitemsF:
            if shopchoice in text2:
                print(text2)
                if int(text2[-3:]) >= gold:
                    print("You need another", int(text2[-3:]) - gold, "gold.")
                    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
                    break
                elif int(text2[-3:]) <= gold:
                    print("You have purchased,", text2[:-11]+".")
                    x = (int(text2[-21:-18]))
                    gold = gold - int(text2[-3:])
                    found = True

        for text2 in shopitemsM:
            if shopchoice in text2:
                print(text2)
                if int(text2[-3:]) >= gold:
                    print("You need another", int(text2[-3:]) - gold, "gold.")
                    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
                    break
                elif int(text2[-3:]) <= gold:
                    print("You have purchased,", text2[:-11]+".")
                    x = (int(text2[-21:-18]))
                    gold = gold - int(text2[-3:])
                    found = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added another answer here to solve the problem mykill456 raised in the comment above about wanting to access the "x = (int(text2[-21:-18]))" variable outside of the go_to_shop() function.

```
def go_to_shop():
    global y

    shopitemsF = ["Ghostblade: 150 Damage, Cost: 700", "Thunderblade: 120 Damage, Cost: 300", "Bloodcursed Sword: 160 Damage, Cost 800"]
    shopitemsM = ["Fire Throw: 150 Damage, Cost: 700", "Ice Wind: 120 Damage, Cost: 300", "Electric shock: 160 Damage, Cost 800"]


    print("Welcome to the shop.")
    print('')
    if character == "Fighter":
        g = ', '
        print(g.join(shopitemsF))
        time.sleep(1)
    elif character == "Mage":
        g = ', '
        print(g.join(shopitemsM))
        time.sleep(1)

    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
    print('')

    found = False
    while found != True:
        for text2 in shopitemsF:
            if shopchoice in text2:
                print(text2)
                if int(text2[-3:]) >= gold:
                    print("You need another", int(text2[-3:]) - gold, "gold.")
                    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
                    break
                elif int(text2[-3:]) <= gold:
                    print("You have purchased,", text2[:-11]+".")
                    y = (int(text2[-21:-18]))
                    gold = gold - int(text2[-3:])
                    found = True

        for text2 in shopitemsM:
            if shopchoice in text2:
                print(text2)
                if int(text2[-3:]) >= gold:
                    print("You need another", int(text2[-3:]) - gold, "gold.")
                    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
                    break
                elif int(text2[-3:]) <= gold:
                    print("You have purchased,", text2[:-11]+".")
                    y = (int(text2[-21:-18]))
                    gold = gold - int(text2[-3:])
                    found = True

y = 0

x = input("If you want to go to shop type 'Yes'")
if x == "Yes":
    go_to_shop()
    print('here is y:', y)
```

Comment: Ok everything was working an thanks for your time I just need you to check one last thing. The function isn't getting called now and Im not sure why. It was working before and I think its something small. Heres a link to my full code. https://pastebin.com/c61eeSBA

Comment: you set y = 0 before the monster fight, so every time you fight the monster your health never goes down because j = j - y, so you enter an infinite loop.  Do you want to go to the shop first to initialize y?

Comment: Yes. Id like it so after they choose the first weapon it goes straight the shop. I don't know why but like on friday the function would run an now Im not sure why it just skips the whole function

Comment: ok, then move the last 3 lines (shopagain = input("If you want to go to shop type 'Yes'")
if shopagain == "Yes":
    go_to_shop()) to just after the y = 0 line.

Comment: It is saying something about the gold being local. Could you run the pastebin I sent you because you can try your answer and see whats wrong. Like I feel I've changed something without realising.

Comment: OK, I ran the pastebin by taking the last 3 lines and moving them just after the y = 0.  To get past the gold being local issue you have to update the first line of go_to_shop to be "global y, gold".  I did that and I got through and defeated the monster!

Comment: YES. hahaha you defeated the monster indeed. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you basically have it.  You need to create a function and call that function.

```
x = input("If you want to go to shop type 'Yes'")
if x == "Yes":
    go_to_shop()

def go_to_shop():
    <insert your big block of code here>
```

Make sure you indent the big block of code so it appears to the right of the "def go_to_shop():".  Python uses indention instead of braces {} to enclose function blocks.

Comment: When I put the block of code into the function the x = (int(text2[-21:-18])) becomes unusable out of the function is there a way to fix it.

Comment: yes, rename x to y (since you already defined x = input("...")) and then define y outside the function.

Comment: Just a little confused. Do you mean rename the x that is outside the function to y. And do you mean use the def function to define it.

Comment: I couldn't fit the whole thing in this comment so I added an additional answer to clarify what I'm talking about.  Note the "global y" to at the top that lets you access y outside of the function.  You could also return it in the function.  Please accept answer if either of these are helpful to you.